# How to get non-standard items in an RSS feed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

I'm just trying to parse an RSS feed here, I can do this with the XmlReader

```
String blogrss = @"http://belvederecollegeac.wordpress.com/feed/";

             using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(blogrss))
    {
        System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed feed = System.ServiceModel.Syndication.SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);

        foreach (var v in feed.Items)
        {
            string title = v.Title.Text.Replace("•", "  ---  ");
            string url = v.Id; 

            string link = "<a href=" + url + ">" + title + "</a>"; 

            Response.Write(link + "<br><br>");

        }
```

But I can't find how the xml reader given me the description node?

I can get v.Tite and v.Id (for the link), but the RSS contains a description node such as this

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
Photos from the J.C.T. game v Kilkenny College can be viewed at the College website gallery page. A highlights video from the S.C.T. game v Terenure can also be viewed on the video gallery page.<img alt="" border="0" src="http://stats.wordpress.com/b.gif?host=belvederecollegeac.wordpress.com&#038;blog=41877065&#038;post=92&#038;subd=belvederecollegeac&#038;ref=&#038;feed=1" width="1" height="1" />
]]>
</description>
```

my `feed.Items` collection doesn't seem to have an object attached to it called description?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Description property. Use Summary property. It is described in the following documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationitem.summary.aspx

"When serialized to Atom 1.0, this property is written to a summary element. When serialized to RSS 2.0, this property is written to a description element."